# Load pre-selected values in Kendo Multiselect

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I use Kendo MultiSelect in my project.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
            placeholder: "--Select Public Houses--",
            dataTextField: "PublicHouseName",
            dataValueField: "PublicHouseId",
            autoBind: true,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "/book/getallpublichouses"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I pass selected values in multiselect and set their as preselected?

Answer (score 1):

You can select values based on your `dataValueField`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
            placeholder: "--Select Public Houses--",
            dataTextField: "PublicHouseName",
            dataValueField: "PublicHouseId",
            autoBind: true,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "/book/getallpublichouses"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //selects your object with the PublicHouseIds of 25 and 30
        //pass in as strings
        $("#multiselect").getKendoMultiSelect().value(["25", "30"]);
    });
</script>
```

Here is a demo to play around with: http://dojo.telerik.com/IMUXaJaM/2

Comment: I add the book in one view and edit it in another, so i need to get public houses IDs in prop List<int> from added book and pass them into edit view in kendo multi select

Comment: I don't see a problem here. pass them into a function and then set the values. Besides. Your question does not offer any information on where this should come from or how you would obtain these values. How you use this is totally up to you I'm afraid